# What is dual space, and why is it required?

Tags: quantum-state, linear-algebra, terminology-and-notation

I recently started QC/QM and came across something called dual space? How do we explain  concept of dual space to a layman. why do we need dual space?

I tried to read and watch some resources on dual space but couldn't understand them as they are too technical for me as of now. I could vaguely understand that dual space is like shadow of real thing. Everything in universe exists in duality like sad-happy, rich-poor etc...but couldn't understand what exactly it is, why it is needed and how it helps?

Comment: Have you check this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/281635/what-is-the-physical-significance-of-the-dual-space-in-qm ?

Comment: Simple answer from Quora: Andrew Winkler, former Professor at Columbia University
Q: I'm facing a problem understanding dual spaces on a linear functional. What are some helpful lecture videos or links?
A: Think of vectors as column vectors. Think of linear functionals (the dual space) as row vectors. When you multiply a row vector by a column vector, you get a number. So a row vector is a linear functional on column vectors, and also a column vector is a linear functional on row vectors. The row vectors are dual to the column vectors, and the column vectors are dual to the row vectors.

Comment: @Mariusz why is it like without dual space of vector we cannot derive information?
"In short, a state ket as such, even though represent the physical system and is postulated to be containing all the physical information about the system that are allowed to ask, we cannot derive the information from it unless we make use of it's dual in the bra space."

source: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/281648/333041

Comment: Here is best explanation https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3749/why-do-we-care-about-dual-spaces: The dual is intuitively the space of "rulers" (or measurement-instruments) of our vector space. Its elements measure vectors. This is what makes the dual space and its relatives so important in Differential Geometry, for instance.